# Postman post request returning null

Tags: php, mysql, post, postman

I'm making an android application that can upload multiple image to server, to make sure that my php is working, i'm trying it on postman, but when i try it on postman the response is null

this is the reponse i get from postman

[this is the body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llQP5.png)

[this is the result i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2XPP.png)

i've reading some website for tutorial of this app and write the php exactly like that but it's keep sending null on my post request

[Android Upload Image using Android Upload Service](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/)

[Android Upload Image From Gallery To Server Using PHP MySQL](https://androidjson.com/android-upload-image-server-using-php-mysql/)

[Android Upload Image to Server Using PHP MySQL](https://prodevsblog.com/view/android-upload-image-to-server-using-php-mysql/)

[Android Upload Image to Server Using PHP and MySQL](http://www.androidcodefinder.com/blog/2018/02/04/android-upload-image-to-server-using-php-mysql/)

This is my php

```
<?php 
//importing dbDetails file 
    require_once 'dbDetails.php';

    //this is our upload folder 
    $upload_path = 'upload/';

    //Getting the server ip 
    $server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

    //creating the upload url 
    $upload_url = 'http://'.$server_ip.'/opr57/'.$upload_path; 

    //response array 
    $response = array(); 


    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

        //checking the required parameters from the request 
        if(isset($_POST['nama']) and isset($_FILES['image']['foto_ktp'])){

            //connecting to the database 
            $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect...');

            //getting name from the request 
            $id_dropping = $_POST['id_dropping'];
            $nama = $_POST['nama'];
            $alamat = $_POST['alamat'];
            $tr = $_POST['tr'];
            $parkiran = $_POST['parkiran'];
            $resort = $_POST['resort'];
            $pinjaman = $_POST['pinjaman'];
            $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
            $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
            $ktp = $_POST['foto_ktp'];
            $nasabah = $_POST['foto_nasabah'];
            $status = $_POST['status'];
            $ktpinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['foto_ktp']);
            $nasabahinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['foto_nasabah']);
            $extensionktp = $ktpinfo['extension'];
            $extensionnasabah = $nasabahinfo['extension'];
            $ktpurl = $upload_url.getFileName().'.'.$extensionktp;
            $ktppath = 
$upload_path.getFileName().'.'.$extensionktp;
            $nasabahurl = $upload_url.getFileName().'.'.$extensionnasabah;
            $nasabahpath = $upload_path.getFileName().'.'.$extensionnasabah;



            //trying to save the file in the directory 
            try{
                //saving the file 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_nama'],$ktppath);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_nama'],$nasabahpath);
            try{
            //saving the file 
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$file_path);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'],$file_path2);
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO dropping(id_dropping, nama, alamat, tr, parkiran, resort , pinjaman ,latitude,longitude,foto_ktp,foto_nasabah status) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssss", $id_dropping,$name,$alamat,$tr,$parkiran,$resort,$pinjaman,$latitude,$longitude,$file_url,$file_url2,$status);
            //$sql = "INSERT INTO `opr57`.`dropping` (`id_dropping`,`nama`,`alamat`,`tr`,`parkiran`,`resort`,`pinjaman`,`latitude`,`longitude`,`foto_ktp`,`foto_nasabah`,`status`) VALUES ('$id_dropping', '$name', '$alamat', '$tr', '$parkiran', '$resort', '$pinjaman','$latitude', '$longitude', '$file_url', '$file_url2', '$status');";


            //adding the path and name to database 
            //if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
            if($stmt->execute()){

                //filling response array with values 
                $response['error'] = false; 
                $response['url'] = $file_url; 
                $response['url2'] = $file_url2;
                $response['name'] = $name;
            }
            else{
                $error = $mysqli->errno . ' ' . $mysqli->error;
echo $error; // 1054 Unknown column 'foo' in 'field list'
        //if some error occurred 
        }}catch(Exception $e){
            $response['error']=true;
            $response['message']=$e->getMessage();
        }       
            //displaying the response 
            echo json_encode($response);

            //closing the connection 
            mysqli_close($con);
        }else{
            $response['error']=true;
            $response['message']='Please choose a file';
        }
    }
```

i expect the output to be like this `{"error":false,"url":"http:\/\/192.168.43.149\/opr57\/upload\/9.jpg","url2":"http:\/\/192.168.43.149\/opr57\/upload\/9.jpg""name":"Bayu"}`, but the actual output is like this

```
    <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in D:\xampp\htdocs\opr57\upload.php:63
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in
<b>D:\xampp\htdocs\opr57\upload.php</b> on line
<b>63</b>
<br />
```

I'm really looking forward for an answer.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changing my code to using prepared statement and it worked like a charm

here's where i change my code

Before

```
try{
            //saving the file 
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$file_path);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'],$file_path2);
            //$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO dropping(id_dropping, nama, alamat, tr, parkiran, resort , pinjaman ,latitude,longitude,foto_ktp,foto_nasabah status) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            //$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssss", $id_dropping,$name,$alamat,$tr,$parkiran,$resort,$pinjaman,$latitude,$longitude,$file_url,$file_url2,$status);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `opr57`.`dropping` (`id_dropping`,`nama`,`alamat`,`tr`,`parkiran`,`resort`,`pinjaman`,`latitude`,`longitude`,`foto_ktp`,`foto_nasabah`,`status`) VALUES ('$id_dropping', '$name', '$alamat', '$tr', '$parkiran', '$resort', '$pinjaman','$latitude', '$longitude', '$file_url', '$file_url2', '$status');";


            //adding the path and name to database 
            //if($stmt->execute())
            if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

                //filling response array with values 
                $response['error'] = false; 
                $response['url'] = $file_url; 
                $response['url2'] = $file_url2;
                $response['name'] = $name;
            }


        //if some error occurred 
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $response['error']=true;
            $response['message']=$e->getMessage();
        }
```

After

```
        try{
            //saving the file 
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$file_path);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'],$file_path2);
            $stmt ="INSERT INTO dropping(id_dropping, nama, alamat, tr, parkiran, resort , pinjaman ,latitude,longitude,foto_ktp,foto_nasabah,status) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            //$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssss", $id_dropping,$name,$alamat,$tr,$parkiran,$resort,$pinjaman,$latitude,$longitude,$file_url,$file_url2,$status);
            //$sql = "INSERT INTO `opr57`.`dropping` (`id_dropping`,`nama`,`alamat`,`tr`,`parkiran`,`resort`,`pinjaman`,`latitude`,`longitude`,`foto_ktp`,`foto_nasabah`,`status`) VALUES ('$id_dropping', '$name', '$alamat', '$tr', '$parkiran', '$resort', '$pinjaman','$latitude', '$longitude', '$file_url', '$file_url2', '$status');";


            //adding the path and name to database 
            //if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
            if($stat = $conn->prepare($stmt)){
                $stat->bind_param("ssssssssssss", $id_dropping,$name,$alamat,$tr,$parkiran,$resort,$pinjaman,$latitude,$longitude,$file_url,$file_url2,$status);
                $stat->execute();
                //filling response array with values 
                $response['error'] = false; 
                $response['url'] = $file_url; 
                $response['url2'] = $file_url2;
                $response['name'] = $name;
            }
            else{
                $error = $conn->errno . ' ' . $conn->error;
                echo $error; 
        //if some error occurred 
        }}catch(Exception $e){
            $response['error']=true;
            $response['message']=$e->getMessage();
        }
```

I've decide to use prepared statement based on @Dharman Advice thanks to that i am changing my code to above code

well, actually my problem with that code before is just some typo on `status` where there is another comma after status and there's no comma before `status`

I give many thanks to everyone who's giving me advice and answer to this problem

Comment: Its not helping me at all, and after i see that possible duplicate and not finding the answer i was looking for i starting to see my code and i found out what is wrong

Comment: @Dharman well, can you give me the right answer based on my problem? well, i've tried the prepared statement and this error shows up `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in D:\xampp\htdocs\opr57\upload.php:61`, can you give me the answer of this?

Answer (score -1):

First, remove or comment this code

```html
//displaying the response 
echo json_encode($response);
```

Then add this to your code bro..

```html
header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
return print json_encode( $response );
```

```html
<?php 
//importing dbDetails file 
require_once 'dbDetails.php';

//this is our upload folder 
$upload_path = 'upload/';

//Getting the server ip 
$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

//creating the upload url 
$upload_url = 'http://'.$server_ip.'/opr57/'.$upload_path; 

//response array 
$response = array(); 
$response['error'] = true; 


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    //checking the required parameters from the request 
    if(isset($_POST['nama']) and isset($_FILES['image']['foto_ktp'])){

        //connecting to the database 
        $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect...');

        //getting name from the request 
        $id_dropping = $_POST['id_dropping'];
        $nama = $_POST['nama'];
        $alamat = $_POST['alamat'];
        $tr = $_POST['tr'];
        $parkiran = $_POST['parkiran'];
        $resort = $_POST['resort'];
        $pinjaman = $_POST['pinjaman'];
        $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
        $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
        $ktp = $_POST['foto_ktp'];
        $nasabah = $_POST['foto_nasabah'];
        $status = $_POST['status'];
        $ktpinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['foto_ktp']);
        $nasabahinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['foto_nasabah']);
        $extensionktp = $ktpinfo['extension'];
        $extensionnasabah = $nasabahinfo['extension'];
        $ktpurl = $upload_url.getFileName().'.'.$extensionktp;
        $ktppath = $upload_path.getFileName().'.'.$extensionktp;
        $nasabahurl = $upload_url.getFileName().'.'.$extensionnasabah;
        $nasabahpath = $upload_path.getFileName().'.'.$extensionnasabah;


        //saving the file 
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_nama'],$ktppath);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_nama'],$nasabahpath);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `opr57`.`dropping` (`id_dropping`,`nama`,`alamat`,`tr`,`parkiran`,`resort`,`pinjaman`,`latitude`,`longitude`,`foto_ktp`,`foto_nasabah`,`status`) 
            VALUES ('$id_dropping', '$nama', '$alamat', '$tr', '$parkiran', '$resort', '$pinjaman','$latitude', '$longitude', '$ktpurl', '$nasabahurl', '$status',);";

            //adding the path and name to database 
            if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
                //filling response array with values 
                $response['error'] = false; 
                $response['url'] = $ktpurl;                
                $response['name'] = $nama;
            }

        //closing the connection 
        mysqli_close($con);
    }else{
        $response['message']='Please choose a file';
    }
}

header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
return print json_encode( $response );
```

Comment: Ok, i will try this one, thank you

Comment: @Dharman can you help me to get the reference or give an example with my code?

Comment: when i try it it give an error like this {
    "error": true,
    "message": "Please choose a file"
}